# How can i upload files to file.io using cloud flare workers[javascript]?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, worker, cloudflare-workers

These recent days I tryed multiple times to upload file to file.io using cfworkers but it returns error this is my source code:

```
  async function handleRequest() {
const file = fetch('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b1/02_start_book_creator.png/640px-02_start_book_creator.png');
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file);
 var returned=fetch('https://file.io', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
});


 return returned
    }
    addEventListener("fetch", event => {
      return event.respondWith(handleRequest())
      })
```

The error is this:

```
{"success":false,"error":400,"message":"Trouble uploading file"}
```

What i have to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of this writing, Cloudflare Workers doesn't support the [`File` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) and thus can't construct `FormData` containing filenames and types, which is probably what you need here.

However, coincidentally, we're planning to roll out support for this very soon -- this week or next week. Once we've done that, you can construct your `FormData` containing `File` objects, like so:

```js
let response = await fetch('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b1/02_start_book_creator.png/640px-02_start_book_creator.png');
let data = await response.arrayBuffer();
let file = new File([data], "640px-02_start_book_creator.png", {type: "image/png"})
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file);
```

Comment: @teammeryb it's not rolled out yet, thus it returns an error. You need to wait for a few weeks as Kenton said.